# List Failure - Permission - Error at Power Apps OnStart

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions

Am I correct to assume that everyone who will be viewing the data in a Power Apps user interface will not only require permission on the Power Apps side, and but because the lists are in SharePoint, they'll also require permission to access the SP site where the lists that feed the Power Apps are stored?

I am running some tests with new members and they are getting an error message at app OnStart that reads:

"You don't have permission to view this data. Server Response: MemberList failed: Something went wrong"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Everyone who will be viewing the data in a Power Apps that is linked to a SharePoint list will need at least **View Only** permission on the list itself.

You can grant the users with [unique permission on the list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782) only, or adjust their permissions in this site if you do not want them to have access to other locations.

Comment: I understand.

What about group permissions? Can I use an SP list as an employee group and grant them all the same permission based on the list name?

Such as, all staff on 'MemberList' is granted permission level View only? Or must each member be added individually?

Comment: @Curtis You can grant user permissions using a group, as long as the group has at least View Only permission on the list. Create a SharePoint group in the site and then add the users to the group, then grant permission to the group via Permissions page. See the tutorial here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-group-and-add-a-user-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: Can I use a SP 'Member List' that I've already created that has the names an emails of all the Member needing access as the source of group data for the permissions? Or do I have to add each member individually to an SP permissions group that I create?

Comment: @Curtis You will need to add the users to the SharePoint group for permission management. A SharePoint list does not pass permission inheritance for you.

Comment: Is a SP user, by default, required to enter each name in the SP group one at a time, or can/will a/several large mass cut and paste work?

Comment: @Curtis One at a time to be added in a SharePoint group.